# Sencha cmd 4 adding css and js

Tags: extjs, build, cmd, sencha-cmd

In the lastest versión on sencha cmd 4.1 and 4.2 , i can't add external css and js inside the app.json it throws Mixed-Mode x-compile and microload markup is currently unsupported , seems that I need to remove and move everything inside the index.html x-compile comment tag to the app.json but it throws me a null pointer in the building , anyone have a real example on how to accomplish this ?? in 4.1 or 4.2  using extjs 4.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Just put your css outside of `<x-compile>` block in `index.html` and it will work. I use this approach many times at http://extjs.eu/examples where I need to load 3rd party CDN hosted css files.

Another option would be to copy and paste the css to sass/src/xxx.sass but that is not probably feasible for you.

Comment: Hi Saki, I had the same problem and moving those outside x-compile worked, but its not possible to get that minified also?

Comment: @VAAA if it is your file, then copy&paste its content into a sass file. If it is 3rd party, then it's better to load it separately from others because of possible 3rd party bug fixes or upgrades.

Comment: Hi Saki, appreciate it a lot. Some css are mine, some are awesomefont and some brytum scheduler. Can I post a new question about how to do the sass stuff? Appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Saki, I just create the following question. Appreciate so much your always support and help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810223/how-to-create-custom-sass-in-extjs-for-compiling-with-sencha-cmd

Answer (score 0):

if u want to create a custom css then

go to C:\xampp\htdocs\SlideNave-WithBarCharts\resources\sass

and  create a new custom.scss file like this

```
   @import 'custom/css3';

@mixin buttonize($base_color: #5291C5, $button_size: 30px) {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;

line-height: $button_size;

padding: 0 $button_size/2;
height: $button_size;
@include border-radius($button_size/2);
border: 1px solid darken($base_color, 20%);
text-shadow: darken($base_color, 10%) 0 -1px 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    margin: 50px;
  }
  .button {
    @include buttonize;
  }

  .green_button {
    @include buttonize(#3A8A20); // Green
  }
```

and type

compass compile sass

then check the css file created under

C:\xampp\htdocs\SlideNave-WithBarCharts\resources\css (custom.css)

( befrore that install compass in your machine  **gem install compass**)