# How to create custom SASS in ExtJS for compiling with Sencha CMD

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

I have my application built with `ExtJS 4.2.1`

My app structure was generated using `Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45.`

Im using some custom CSS in my app to give personalized style so my `XTemplate` items and also Im using `AwesomeFont` and `FamFam` Sprites for icons.

This is my resources directory in my app sencha cmd structure:

[image]

- App.css is a custom CSS
- BoxSelect.css is other custom CSS
- chooser.css is other custom CSS
- famfamfam.css is the CSS that will handle the famfam.png image sprite
- font.css is the CSS that comes with AwesomeFont.

The application in development mode (without building) works great, but when I tried to build using Sencha CMD and then try to open the **production** Index.html I couldn't see any icon neither the styles applied from my custom CSS's files.

So what I ended up was to modify my app Index.html in order to move all my CSS references outside the  tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Application</title>


    <!-- <x-compile> -->
    <!-- <x-bootstrap> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">


    <script src="ext/ext-dev.js"></script>

    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- </x-bootstrap> -->


     <!-- Ext Scheduler -->
     <script src="lib/js/sch-all-debug.js"></script>

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.vegas.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

     <!-- Ext Scheduler -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/sch-all-neptune.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/jquery.vegas.min.css">

    <script src="app/Constants.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Glyphs.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <!-- </x-compile> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/boxselect.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/famfamfam.css">
    <!-- view icons chooser style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/chooser.css">


</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Doing this way worked fine but I would like to create a SASS so my custom CSS's files can be minified.

Any clue on what are the steps that I have to follow in order to create my SASS for my custom CSS's so when doing `sencha app build production` my CSS are minified?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application folder, there should be `sass` folder. Move your CSS stylesheets to `sass/etc/` and rename to `*.scss`, then run `sencha app build`. This should do the trick.

One caveat: I recall there was a bug in Cmd at some point, it didn't pick up extra SCSS files. If the above solution does not work for you, manually concatenate all CSS files into `sass/etc/all.scss` and it should work then.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, yes I have a SASS folder. I will move the files there. Do I have to change something in my Index.html? Or leaving there as .css will work? Appreciate it

Comment: Yes, after moving CSS to `sass/etc/` just remove their links from the boilerplate HTML - Sencha Cmd should compile them into one huge CSS file and place a link to that file in HTML.

Comment: Amazing :) let me do that and will let you know my result

Comment: Great it worked, the only ones that didn't work was FontAwesome.css and FamFamFam.css (this is a sprite). Didn't know why it didn't work maybe the order of the css affect something.

Comment: Check if FontAwesome.css and FamFamFam.css were included in the compiled CSS sheet. It may also be helpful to run `sencha -debug app build` to see if Cmd recognizes the files; be prepared to sift through a _ton_ of output though, debug is very verbose.

Comment: Yes actually it only worked using all.scss and it generates three css: all.css, all_01.css and all_02.css. If I open all_01.css I can see that the famfamfam.css (sprite css) is there but somehow when I open my app is not working. I think that famfamfam css part should be loaded after. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to affect the order in which the SASS files are compiled; there's some deep internal logic involved. If you really need famfamfam.css to be loaded after the rest of CSS, keep it separate as you did before; I would strongly recommend to try finding out why it doesn't work instead, as it may cause you some grief down the road. Maybe some class names are clashing? That would be bad for maintenance.

Comment: I think It was a mistake.. the url(../images) now is just url(images). Think I fixed. :)

Comment: It worked now... the only one that didnt work is famfamfam.css, I fix the sprite image location (now is not 404 not found) but the images are not correct. Maybe there is an issue with sprite images.